# C Code for Hexadecimal without using standard libraries

Tags: c

I want to write C Code which converts first string into integer then integer into hexadecimal.
ex: I have Ip iddress as "172.24.18.240" now first find out first dot from it and take the number before it that is "172" convert it into integer then convert it inti hexadecimal and it should do the same for all like 24,18,240 and convert into long/integer value

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you get stuck on exactly?

Comment: `strcpy` is a C Standard Library function.

Comment: Ya i can use strcpy how to proceed..

Comment: Means I cannot use find function for finding the dots in Ip address.

Comment: No actually i want to use this code in driver as i am dot net developer i am facing writing C code.

Comment: @Swapnil strchr is like find.

Comment: @Swapnil: Then why the requirement to use no library functions?  That smells like homework to me too.

Comment: If you want to write a **C** function, please don't tag is as C++.

Comment: Can you do this conversion on paper in longhand?  The algorithm is very straightforward.

Comment: @Software Monkey He already said it's for a driver. Perhaps he has access to libraries but doesn't realize it. In any case, all these "homework smell" comments are redundant and unhelpful.

Comment: I would add that a peak at his profile makes it clear that he's not just doing homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h> // testing
int main(int argc, char** argv) // testing
{
    char* ipString = argc > 1? argv[1] : "172.24.18.240"; // testing
    char* ip = ipString;
    unsigned int hex;

    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
        unsigned int n = 0;
        for( char c; (c = *ip) >= '0' && c <= '9'; ip++ )
            n = 10 * n + c - '0';
        hex = (hex << 8) + n;

        if( *ip == '.' ) ip++;
    }

     printf("%08X\n", hex); // testing
     return 0; // testing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
char sn[4];
char *nid = hexString;

int nip[4];
int xnip[4];
int j = 0;
while (*nid != '\0') {
  int i = 0;
  memset(sn, '\0', sizeof sn);
  while (isdigit(*nid)) {
    sn[i++] = *nid++;
  }
  if (*nid == '.')
    nid++;

  // now sn should be the number part
  nip[j] = your_str_to_int(sn);
  xnip[j] = your_int_to_hex(nip[j]);
  j++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
    char hexChars[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    char ipString[] = "172.24.18.254"; 
    char hexString[9] = "";
    const char* pch = ipString;

    int num = 0;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        if (*pch != '.' && *pch != '\0')
        {
            num *= 10;
            num += (*pch - '0');
        }
        else
        {
            hexString[i++] = hexChars[num / 16];
            hexString[i++] = hexChars[num % 16];
            num = 0;
        }
    } while (*pch++);

    return 0;
}
```

The hex values will stored in `hexString`.

Comment: Thanks Marlon. In this above code i guess you are not converting char to Integer as stated above in my question.

Comment: @Swapnil num is an integer, isn't it? If this (which does approximately the same thing my code does) doesn't do what you want, it's because you did a poor job of specifying what you want.

Comment: Do you want the final value stored in an integer?

Comment: @Marlon He probably does, and we were misled by his hexString array (which he oddly copied his IP address into). I wonder if this sort of thing is really a good use of SO -- if he's stuck here, he will keep getting stuck, until he learns how to program.

Comment: @Marlon : ya i want the final value to convert in integer.How to achieve that ?

Comment: @Jim Balter : Which answer ? You didn't gave any answer only comments.

Comment: @Swapnil My answer has been up for over 3 hours.

Answer (score -1):

```
    int i = 0, sum = 0;
    char ipString[] = "172.24.18.240";
    do
    {
            if (isdigit(ipString[i])) sum = sum * 10 + ipString[i] - '0';
            else
            {       putchar("0123456789ABCDEF"[sum / 16]);
                    putchar("0123456789ABCDEF"[sum % 16]);
                    putchar('.');
                    sum = 0;
            }
    }
    while (ipString[i++] != '\0');
```

More or less ugly, but should work on IP addresses.